# Loading content from subpage while keeping entered url via htaccess doesn't work and takes subpage url instead

Tags: .htaccess

I have two CMS which should sown on the same domain. 
Depending how the url looks htaccess sends the quest to TYPO3 or Wordpress. 
Without the ProxyPass/Reverse the htaccess loads the content but change the url to the cms url but I want to keep my entered URL. 
When I upload the ProxyPass variables i get a 500 error. 
But when i keep the  the 500 error disapears.

What did I miss?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?route-root.domain\.de$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.route-wp.domain.de/$1 [NC,P,L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_proxy.c>
    ProxyPass / http://www.route-wp.domain.de/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://www.route-wp.domain.de/
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess, i did nothing wrong in particular.  
My guess is that my host don't let me use this directives. 
 
When I tried to create a logfile via `ErrorLog` I also get a 500.